# How would I form a fetch result predicate based on this data model?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest

[image]

How would I return all the ingredients related to recipes, specifically from recipes that belong to events? And then order them by aisle?

Further explanation:

User has a "recipe book" of Recipe objects, which has a relationship to Ingredients. The user will associate a Recipe to an Event when they plan on preparing the Recipe. The data I'm trying to pull out is the list of Ingredients that belong to Recipes, that belong to Events, ordered by Aisle. Basically a "grocery list".

Further explanation on what an Event object is:
Events allow for duplicate recipes. Say I am going to have a fried egg (ingredient = "1 fresh egg") for 3 consecutive days (3 separate events), I want the shopping list to contain "1 fresh egg" three times - one instance for each event.

Here is my fetch request, which is not returning any results - I assume the crux of the issue is the predicate:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ingredient"    inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[request setEntity:entity];

// get ingredients of recipes that belong to events
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ingredient.recipe == Event.recipe"]];

// sort by "aisle"
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorCategory = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"aisle" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorCategory, nil];

// create nsfrc with "aisle" as sectionNameKeyPath
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"aisle" cacheName:@"MyFRCCache"];
frc.delegate = self;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![frc performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
self.fetchedResultsController = frc;
```

Thanks to Martin R's question, I have further fleshed out the problem. Here is some sample data and the desired output:

### Recipe

Z_PK = 1, ZTITLE = "Oatmeal"
Z_PK = 2, ZTITLE = "Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich"
Z_PK = 3, ZTITLE = "Grilled Cheese Sandwich"
Z_PK = 4, ZTITLE = "Beef Stew"
Z_PK = 5, ZTITLE = "Hamburger"
... Plus more recipes that wouldn't be included in fetch results ...

### Event

Z_PK = 1, ZTITLE = "Breakfast 1", ZRECIPE = 1
Z_PK = 2, ZTITLE = "Lunch 1", ZRECIPE = 2
Z_PK = 3, ZTITLE = "Dinner ", ZRECIPE = 4
Z_PK = 4, ZTITLE = "Breakfast 2", ZRECIPE = 1  // Note repeat of recipe
Z_PK = 5, ZTITLE = "Lunch 2", ZRECIPE = 3
Z_PK = 6, ZTITLE = "Dinner 2", ZRECIPE = 5

### Ingredient

Z_PK = 1, ZTITLE = "1 cup oatmeal", ZRECIPE = 1, ZAISLE = 4
Z_PK = 2, ZTITLE = "2 cups milk", ZRECIPE = 1, ZAISLE = 2
Z_PK = 3, ZTITLE = "2 pieces white bread", ZRECIPE = 2, ZAISLE = 5
Z_PK = 4, ZTITLE = "1 tbsp. jelly", ZRECIPE = 2, ZAISLE = 4
Z_PK = 5, ZTITLE = "1 tbsp peanut butter", ZRECIPE = 2, ZAISLE = 4
Z_PK = 6, ZTITLE = "2 pieces rye bread", ZRECIPE = 3, ZAISLE = 5
Z_PK = 7, ZTITLE = "1 cheese slice", ZRECIPE = 3, ZAISLE = 2
Z_PK = 8, ZTITLE = "1 lbs. chuck roast", ZRECIPE = 4, ZAISLE = 3
Z_PK = 9, ZTITLE = "2 carrots", ZRECIPE = 4, ZAISLE = 1
Z_PK = 10, ZTITLE = "2 potatoes", ZRECIPE = 4, ZAISLE = 1
Z_PK = 11, ZTITLE = "1 hamburger bun", ZRECIPE = 5, ZAISLE = 5
Z_PK = 12, ZTITLE = "1/4 pound hamburger", ZRECIPE = 5, ZAISLE = 3

### Aisle

Z_PK = 1, ZTITLE = "Produce", ZDISPLAYORDER = 1
Z_PK = 2, ZTITLE = "Dairy", ZDISPLAYORDER = 2
Z_PK = 3, ZTITLE = "Meats", ZDISPLAYORDER = 3
Z_PK = 4, ZTITLE = "Dry & Canned Items", ZDISPLAYORDER = 4
Z_PK = 5, ZTITLE = "Bakery", ZDISPLAYORDER = 5

### Desired Output (sorted by Aisle ZDISPLAYORDER, bolded items are section titles)

**Produce**
  -2 carrots
  -2 potatoes
**Dairy**
  -2 cups milk
  -2 cups milk // second item because there are two instances of the recipe
  -1 cheese slice
**Meats**
  -1 lbs. chuck roast
  -1/4 pound hamburger
**Dry and Canned Items**
  -1 cup oatmeal
  -1 cup oatmeal // second item because there are two instances of the recipe
  -1 tbsp. jelly
  -1 tbsp peanut butter
**Bakery**
  -2 pieces white bread
  -2 pieces rye bread
  -1 hamburger bun

Comment: What exactly means "recipes that belong to all events"? Do you really want only the recipes that belong to all events in the database? Or do you have a list of events and want the recipes that belong to all events of that list? Or something different?

Comment: I see the confusion. I want a list of recipes associated with the events. In other words - all ingredients in event recipes. I updated the comment in the code, and added further explanation on what an event entails.

Comment: In your relationship model, one event has only one recipe. But in your text you say that an event can have multiple recipes.

Comment: I think that I see now what you are trying to do, but that is perhaps not possible. A fetch request can only return a list of objects (e.g. a list of ingredients) that match certain criteria. The objects can also be sorted. But the result of the fetch request will not contain the same object multiple times! So something like "the shopping list contains '1 fresh egg' three times" is not possible.

Comment: More confusion: You define a `NSFetchedResultsController` that is not used. A FRC normally used to display the result of a fetch request in a table view and for "live updates" of the table when the data changes.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of ingredients, recipes, events and aisles and how the output should look like.

Comment: @MartinR: I have included example data and results, fixed the example code to use the NSFetchedResultController, and simplified the requirements of the Event object so it will not contain multiple recipes. I can see how that adds complexity in the data model. That  will have to wait for the next release...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want a predicate of:

```
recipe.events.@count > 0
```

That would get you `Ingredients` used in any `Recipes` that are for any `Event`.

Or if you're looking for the `Ingredients` used in any `Recipe` for a specific `Event`, that would be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY recipe.events = %@", specificEvent]
```

Your sort descriptor would likely be `aisle.displayOrder`, not just `aisle`.

Answer (score 0):

A fetch request cannot (as far as I know) return duplicate entries of the same managed object. So the closest solution that I have is the following.

Fetch all ingredients and put them into sections according to `aisle.displayOrder`. Within each section, sort the ingredients by their own display order:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"aisle.displayOrder" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"displayOrder" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort1, sort2, nil];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"aisle.displayOrder"
    cacheName:@"fetchControllerCache"];
```

For each ingredient you can then count the number of events (and display that in your table):

```
int numberOfEvents = theIngredient.recipe.events.count;
```